# Django Integrity Error - id cannot be null

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, foreign-key-relationship

I know this has been answered before, but I have been through every answer and nothing either makes sense or I feel like my code is already doing what is being said in the answers.

So I have a model for terms and links, which has a many-to-many relationship.

```
class ProjectTerms(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
    terms = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'project_terms'

class ProjectLinks(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
    links = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    relations = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectTerms)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'project_links'

class ProjectLinksRelations(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # AutoField?
    project_terms = models.ForeignKey('ProjectTerms')
    project_links = models.ForeignKey(ProjectLinks)
```

Script:

```
def create_models(my_term, my_link):
    saved_term = ProjectTerms.objects.update_or_create(terms = my_term)
    saved_link = ProjectLinks.objects.update_or_create(links = my_link)

    ProjectLinksRelations.objects.update_or_create(project_terms=saved_term, project_links=saved_link)
```

A lot of places say that the model (both term and link here) has to be saved before being added to the connecting database.

I've also tried creating each term and link separately and saving them like this:

```
def create_models(my_term, my_link):
    saved_term = ProjectTerms(terms = my_term)
    saved_term.save()
    saved_link = ProjectLinks(links = my_link)
    saved_link.save()

    relation = ProjectLinksRelations.objects.update_or_create(project_terms=saved_term, project_links=saved_link)
    relation.save()
```

Comment: In general you don't need to declare your ID fields like that - Django implicitly creates them. Have you checked your MySQL table schema to confirm that the `id` column for your `ProjectLinksRelation` table is set to auto increment? Also, since you haven't set `ProjectLinksRelation` as the `through` argument to your `ManyToManyField`, it's not actually hooked in to the m2m field - and you probably have a redundant table created for that relationship.

Comment: When I declare the many-to-many relationship and then inspectDB, this is the model code that's generated. I've checked the `ProjectLinksRelation` id which is set to auto-increment. Although I have just noticed the other two aren't, which MySQL won't let me fix because they're referenced in 1ProjectLinksRelation`. But if I drop the tables and start again django syncdb isn't creating the tables properly.

Comment: Are you working from your database back to Django code? Normally inspectDB is something you use to start a Django project from an existing database.

Comment: No, I'm creating the tables from django. I just updated the models with the generated code. I did that for my first table, I just thought I did that for all of them... I'm pretty new to Django.

Comment: Nah, generally you write your code, create your tables from it, and leave it at that. I'll show how I've set up my models for this relationship - a lot of it should be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need for this is:

```
class ProjectTerms(models.Model):
    terms = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProjectLinks(models.Model):
    links = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    relations = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectTerms)
```

The ID fields and the table for the `ManyToManyField` will be automatically created.

To set the `ManyToMany` relationship, use `add`:

```
def create_models(my_term, my_link):
    (saved_term, created) = ProjectTerms.objects.update_or_create(terms = my_term)
    (saved_link, created) = ProjectLinks.objects.update_or_create(links = my_link)
    saved_link.relations.add(saved_term)
    saved_link.save()
```

Comment: Just to be sure, I drop my existing tables change my models to this. When syncing the database though it's adamant it's creating a third table. I've dropped everything again to use migrate db and it's doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Creating the third __table__ is fine and expected. What you don't need is an explicit third __model__.

Comment: Ah, okay. The only problem I have now is it's saying 'tuple' object has no attribute 'relations' when I try to relate the term with the link.

Comment: Oh, right. `update_or_create` returns a tuple indicating whether it created a new object or not, and the object itself. I'll fix that. Also, `update_or_create` is new to the development version - `get_or_create` is what I'd probably use, both since I'm more used to it and because you're not using it to actually update.

Comment: I already fixed that, that's answered on stackoverflow :) 
That is working! Thank you thank you thank you!!!